# Nuspec for NuGet package with UWP project

Tags: c#, dll, xamarin, nuget, uwp

I wont to package one of my DLL in a NuGet package.

This DLL uses Xamarin Forms and will target Android, iOS and UWP (Universal Windows) projects

Here is the  section of nuspec file:

```
  <files>
<!--Core-->
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" target="lib\portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10+UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" target="lib\portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10+UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" target="lib\portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10+UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" />

<!--Xamarin.Android-->
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" target="lib\MonoAndroid10\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" target="lib\MonoAndroid10\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" target="lib\MonoAndroid10\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid.dll" target="lib\MonoAndroid10\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid.dll" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid.pdb" target="lib\MonoAndroid10\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid.pdb" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid.xml" target="lib\MonoAndroid10\CBS_CBT.Polux.Droid.xml" />

<!--Xamarin.iOS-->
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS\bin\iPhone\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" target="lib\Xamarin.iOS10\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS\bin\iPhone\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" target="lib\Xamarin.iOS10\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS\bin\iPhone\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" target="lib\Xamarin.iOS10\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS\bin\iPhone\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS.dll" target="lib\Xamarin.iOS10\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS.dll" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS\bin\iPhone\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS.xml" target="lib\Xamarin.iOS10\CBS_CBT.Polux.iOS.xml" />

<!--uap-->
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" target="lib\UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" target="lib\UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.pri" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" target="lib\UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.dll" target="lib\UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.dll" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.pdb" target="lib\UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.pdb" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.pri" target="lib\UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.pri" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.xml" target="lib\UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.xml" />
```

The problem:

When I run the application, only the CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.dll is copied in the \Debug directory, none of the other files (mainly CBS_CBT.Polx.dll) are copied in the output (\Debug for example) directory. The software then throw:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'CBS_CBT.Polux, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies.

When I manually add only "CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" and "CBS_CBT.Polux.UWP.dll" to the references of the UWP project, the software can run without any issue.

Comment: Co-incidentally, we just updated our documentation to help clarify this scenario a bit more. Does the following documentation help? https://docspreview.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/create-uwp-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Unni Ravindranathan, after reading the doc, I could correct my code.

The only section I had to change was the "Core" one.

Here is the woring nuspec code:

```
<!--Core-->
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" target="lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10+UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.dll" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" target="lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10+UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.pdb" />
<file src="Polux\CBS_CBT.Polux\bin\Release\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" target="lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10+UAP10\CBS_CBT.Polux.xml" />
```